# Using youtube_it gem does not display the list of all videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, youtube-api

i am building a simple rails app to upload my videos to youtube and display the list of my videos on my site. The problem i am facing is that, when i try to display my youtube videos on my index page, my videos are not being displayed. i used this command

```
     helper_method :yt_client
 def yt_client
        @yt_client ||= YouTubeIt::Client.new(:username => YouTubeITConfig.username , :password => YouTubeITConfig.password , :dev_key => YouTubeITConfig.dev_key)
      end
```

an in my index page i have

```
<%= raw yt_client.my_videos %>
```

but i dont see the videos. Does anyone know the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

hey my friend you are very close, this cmd

```
<%= raw yt_client.my_videos %>
```

return just the object, for get the array with all videos you have to call the method **videos**, like this

```
<%= raw yt_client.my_videos.videos %>
```

so you can do something likle this

```
<% yt_client.my_videos.videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= video.title %>
<% end%>
```

tell me if this works for you

cheers!